# Angular 2 Webpack can't find template with AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I get the error

> GET http://localhost:3000/home.component.html 404 (Not Found)

If I change the line in home.component.ts from

```
templateUrl: './home.component.html'
```

to

```
template: require('./home.component.html')
```

everything works, even the stylesUrl which I don't change

So stylesUrl works with

```
styleUrls: [ './home.component.css' ]
```

and doesn't need to change but templateUrl doesn't work using

> ./

but does work using require or absolute path

Code can be found here, I haven't changed anything yet https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter

EDIT: I've just gone through the same steps on a different computer (cloning the repo, installing dependencies, etc), gone to run the project and get the same error.

Comment: Does `styleUrls: require('./home.component.css')` works?

Comment: Could you simply try using `home.component.html`?

Comment: @Kinduser `styles: [require('./home.component.css')]` works as expected

Comment: @Aer0 Same error, 404 on home.component.html

Comment: What's your `baseurl` in your `index.html` file?

Comment: @Kinduser Thanks for your input, found the answer on github https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues/1484 - Change version of "angular2-template-loader" package to "0.6.0"